# Help with this inequality.

Tags: calculus, inequality

This is from Spivak Chapter 1. This is not homework. Please, I'd appreciate hints rather than an outright answer.

Given $|y-y_0|<\frac{|y_0|}{2}$ ; $|y-y_0|<\frac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2}$ and $y_0\neq0$
.

Show that $y\neq0$ and $$\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|<\epsilon$$
So far, I have $$\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|=\left|\frac{y_0}{yy_0}-\frac{y}{yy_0}\right|=\frac{|y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|}<\frac{\epsilon|y_0|}{2|y|}$$

and therefore $$2\frac{|y|}{|y_0|}\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|<\epsilon$$
and it follows from this that:
$$\frac{|y|}{|y_0|}\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|<\epsilon$$

And that's about where I get stuck. Is this not a valid approach, or is there someway I can drop the $\frac{|y|}{|y_0|}$?

Comment: You need to show that $2\lvert y\rvert \geqslant \lvert y_0\rvert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint:***

You've done well. This is a perfectly valid and would soon be a succesful approach. Now use the first inequality

$$ |y - y_{\circ}| \lt \dfrac {y_{\circ}}{2} \implies |y_{\circ}| - |y| \lt \dfrac {y_{\circ}}{2} \implies 0 \lt \dfrac {|y_{\circ}|}{2} \lt |y| \implies \dfrac{1}{2|y|} \lt \dfrac{1}{|y_{\circ}|} $$ to bound $|y|$. The answer shold follow.

Comment: I lost you after the second arrow. Do you think you could elaborate further on that step?

Comment: What I've used is the triangle Inequality, $|x - y| \ge |x| - |y|$ , which you would find somewhere before this exercise in Spivak. The rest should be clear. Ping me if it is not..

Comment: @Josh Infiesto: What follows after the second arrow is just cross multiplication. $ a \gt b $ and $a, b \gt 0$ means $\frac 1 a \lt \frac 1 b$

Comment: I caught the triangle inequality, and I'm clear on the cross multiplication... I just don't know what's happening between steps two and three. To be more specific, where is $0<\frac{|y_0|}{2}<|y|$ coming from? Sorry, I'm a little slow.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The difference to be estimated may be written as follows:

$$\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|=\frac{|y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|} \tag{1}$$

We need to find an upper bound for $1/|y|$ or equivalently a lower bound for $|y|$. Since $|y-y_0|<|y_0|/2$ by the reverse triangle inequality we have $|y|\ge |y_0|-|y-y_0|>|y_0|/2$, and  we found an upper bound for $1/|y|$. Using this in $(1)$ we get

$$\frac{|y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|}<\frac{2|y-y_0|}{|y_0|^2}<\varepsilon$$

Since $|y-y_0|< \varepsilon|y_0|^2/2$. This completes the proof.